# Rails Date and Time user entered isn't in UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date-comparison

I've looked through a lot of issues like this but none seem to correspond to my issue, which is:

I have a Rails app that contains events. Event is a model that has attributes for start date (Date field), start time (Time) and end time (Time). When I created them, I didn't convert any of the entered dates to UTC based times (all times local).

I'm trying to find out if the event is over. I've added a few methods to my model that should help with this, but because I'm comparing Apples (non-UTC) to Oranges (UTC) time. I'm running into a brick wall.

Because I'm mixing Date and Times, I've added the following methods to my Event model:

### helpers

```
  def date_start_time
    return DateTime.new(self.date.year, self.date.month, self.date.day, self.start_time.hour, self.start_time.min, self.start_time.sec)
  end
  def date_end_time
    return DateTime.new(self.date.year, self.date.month, self.date.day, self.end_time.hour, self.end_time.min, self.end_time.sec)
  end
```

### in_past method

```
  def in_past
    logger.debug 'comparing end time: ' + self.date_end_time.to_s +  ' to the current time: ' + DateTime.now.to_s
    self.date_end_time <= DateTime.now
  end
```

I'm loading an event in Rails Console that should end in a few minutes, but I'm getting a true to in_past:

```
1.9.3-p194 :020 > event.in_past
comparing end time: 2013-08-19T20:38:00+00:00 to the current time: 2013-08-19T20:37:22-05:00
 => true
```

I've tried adding .zone to my DateTime.now, but that makes it worse it seems. I feel like I've tried every combination of Zone options here and really I'd just prefer to ignore time zones since all events are currently local.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution to this is add timezone to rails config (application.rb) like this

```
config.time_zone = '<your local timezone>'
```

You can get all the available timezones by

```
#rake time:zones:all
```

Comment: I've tried adding the time zone to the rails config and run into the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is your timezone relative to GMT?

Comment: -500. One of those fields is using it, one isn't. 
`comparing end time: 2013-08-19T20:38:00+00:00 to the current time: 2013-08-19T20:37:22-05:00`

Comment: Ideally, the values coming from database will be converted automatically to config.time_zone. If somehow it is not coming from database you can try  self.date_end_time.in_time_zone

Comment: I think I tried that once before, but I don't remember (tried a million things with this), so I'll try it again.

Comment: Is it also not working for new records? (records saved after you changed time_zone?)

Comment: The problem is I am combining two database fields together (one a time and one a date). Adding `Time.now.zone` to my `date_end_time`method does the trick. Thanks for your help.